# Sencha Touch 2: Additional views in TabPanel

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

I have a TabPanel as a main navigation view in the app. I would like to show a settings view inside the panel of the tabpanel keeping it docked bottom with no actived item, but the settings view is not defined as an item of the tabpanel because I don't want that it appears as a tab.

TabPanel is only showing a view that has been defined as an item. How can I do this?

Comment: https://github.com/praveenbabu/PracticeSencha this is basic tabpanel example check this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have this settings panel stay docked no matter what, don't put it in the TabPanel. Put it in a layout - probably a vbox - that contains both the TabPanel (top) and settings (bottom).

However if you if you actually mean that you want to have it act as an item in the TabPanel, but not have the tab itself show up - you can pass a **tab** config and inside set **hidden** to true.

Comment: Thkns!! I'll hide the tab